# Passing Variables to Query via Beeline

Tags: hiveql, beeline

I need assistance with understanding why my hivevar is not being set in my query?

***This is my beeline statement in a shell script:***

```
Start_Date="20180423"
End_Date="20180424"

beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://#####/default;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=######;' -f ${my_queries}/Count_Query --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --silent=false --hivevar start_date=$Start_Date --hivevar end_date=$End_Date  1>${my_data}/Data_File 2>${my_log}/Log_File
```

***The Query***

```
use sample_db;
select count(*) from sample_table where data_dt>=${start_date} and data_dt<${end_date};
```

***When I look at the data file, which provides a dump of the query, the variables are not properly set to the values.***

```
0: jdbc:hive2://####> use sample_db;
0: jdbc:hive2://####> select count(*) from sample_table where data_dt>=${start_date} and data_dt<${end_date};
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is following part

```
**--hivevar start_date=$Start_Date --hivevar end_date=$End_Date**
```

Remove ** and you are good to go.

**Shell Script.**

```
Start_Date="20180423"
End_Date="20180424"

beeline_cmd="beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://#####/default;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=######;' --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --silent=false"

${beeline_cmd} -f ${my_queries}/Count_Query --hivevar start_date=${Start_Date} --hivevar end_date=${End_Date}  1>${my_data}/Data_File 2>${my_log}/Log_File
```

**Hive Query**

Comment: Actually, those double asterisks were introduced by trying to bold the text in my submission.  They are not part of my code.